# getting ids from a url in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to get the first id from image but instead i'm actually receiving the id after the semicolon. ("id" = 1). Based on my code I don't know how to work around this. Any suggestions. I genuinely do not know how to perform this task. I have tried looking at different resources with no luck.

"http://localhost:4200/image/1;id=1;catergory=testing"

```js
  ngOnInit() {
        const id$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(map((params) => params.get('id') || 0), map(n => Number(n)));
        id$.subscribe(id => {
          this.activeId = id;
          console.log("ActiveId",this.activeId);
          this.testing =  this.graphService.getTestingGraphs(id);
          this.image = this.imageService.getImage(id);
        });
          this.route.params
          .subscribe(params => {
          const id = +params['id'];
          console.log(`Current param ID is: ${id}`);
    });

}
```

Comment: The query parameters are not structured properly. That likely is a major cause of your heartache.

Comment: Like what should be different? I've structuring them different ways. But I still can't get it right.

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to the route event so that any changes in the route with the same url segment will reflect automatically.

Use [window.location.pathname] since the return value of the param is always { id: '1', category: 'testing' }

Try this

```
this.route.params.subscribe(response => {
     //Base in your url "http://localhost:4200/image/1;id=1;catergory=testing"
     //when we access window.location.pathname we get '/image/1;id=1;catergory=testing'

      let path = window.location.pathname.split('/'); // <- output would be ['', 'image', '1;id=1;catergory=testing']
      let myParams = path[2].split(';'); // <- output would be ["1", "id=1", "catergory=testing"]

    //So to get your id
      let id = myParams[0];
});
```

Comment: But, to address my earlier comment, the OP will need to actually build a query string.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your code and what it does. Thank you tho

Comment: How could I see the output of activeId in the log?

Comment: Can we talk in a private chat, because I'm sorta new to this stuff and not quite sure what to do.

Comment: So after splitting the url how do i get the id I want?